# What is the purpose of winter bash?

Tags: discussion

These kinds of activities are fun.  Why do we do them?  To bring joy to ourselves or the users?

Comment: PLOT TWIST: We are the users!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Philosophy Meta can answer this question. The people who run this website (the admins) are in the best position to answer. You should ask on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where they tend to lurk more.

Comment: Even meta.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @Keelan - Yeah, I forgot they opened that up too. Thanks xD